# Java PortScanner, check if port is filtered

Tags: java, sockets, ports

I wrote a port scanner in java that works perfectly fine, however I am not sure how to test if a port is closed and filtered. I have these catch statements that work correctly but I am unsure if my context for them is correct, does TimeoutException mean the socket is filtered? 
I came about this conclusion from previous examples but couldn't find any source explaining it, if not which exceptions would show the socket being closed or filtered?

```
        catch(SocketTimeoutException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Port " + port + " is filtered");
        }
        catch(SocketException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Port " + port + " is closed");
        }
```

Comment: You can't. A correctly filtered port is indistinguishable from an IP address with no host behind it. You get a connect timeout. Any other behaviour from the firewall would constitute an information leak to the attacker. There was a router vendor in the 1990s that issued refusals instead of just dropping the packets, but they quickly learnt the errors their ways.

Comment: @EJP that makes a lot of sense, thanks!